# What is the most efficient way for checking if an object parameter has all require properties?

Tags: javascript

In javascript using an object parameter is my preferred way of working with functions. To check that a function has the required parameters I either (`Solution 1`) loop through all the object parameters properties and throw an error or (`Solution 2`) wait until a required property is needed and throw an error. Solution two seems efficient but I have to throws in multiple places in the function. `Solution 1` seems pragmatic but should probably be a reusable piece of code. Is there another solution I should be looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do this

```
var propsNeeded = ["prop1", "prop2", "blah", "blah", "blah"], 
obj = {
  prop1: "Hi"
}
function hasRequiredProperties(props, obj){
   return Object.keys(obj).sort().join() == propsNeeded.sort().join();
}
console.log(hasRequiredProperties(propsNeeded, obj)); // false
```

You can check for single properties like

```
function hasProperty(propName, obj){
  return obj.hasOwnProperty(propName);
}
```

Comment: this solution solves the problem of checking multiple properties all at once while @Matti solutions would call for multiple calls

Comment: The OP uses the term "required parameters", which suggests perhaps there might also be "non-required (optional)" parameters. This routine eliminates the possibility of optional parameters; it checks that the parameters passed in are exactly identical to those required. That aside, the approach of essentially comparing two arrays by comparing their string representations seems somehow weird, doesn't it? Although this bug would almost never occur in real life, if "a" and "b" were required parameters, then this routine would report success if the object passed in were `{ "a,b" : true }`.

Comment: @torazaburo well, I've included single use version :) Thanks btw

Answer (score 1):

For consistency I would create `require` method and use it always when some property is required.

```
var require = function (key, object) {

    if (typeof object[key] === 'undefined') {
        throw new Error('Required property ' + key + ' is undefined');
    }
};
```

I would test if required property exists as soon as I'm certain that property is needed. Like this:

```
var example = function (args) {

    require('alwaysRequired', args);

    // some code here which uses property alwaysRequired

    if (args.something) {
        require('sometimesRequired', args);

        // some code here which uses property sometimesRequired
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @Amit's answer I'd probably add a method to `Object` itself:

```
Object.prototype.hasAllProperties = function(props, fire){
    var result = Object.keys(this).sort().join() == propsNeeded.sort().join();

    if (fire && !result){
        throw new Error('Object does not define all properties');
    }

    return result;
}
```

and in your function:

```
function someFunction(myObject){
    var objComplete = myObject.hasAllProperties(["prop1", "prop2", "prop3"], false);
}
```

**Update:**

After noticing the problem with @Amit's original answer, here's what I suggest:

```
Object.prototype.hasAllProperties = function(props, fire){
    var result = true;

    $(props).each(function(i, e){
        if (!this.hasOwnProperty(e) ) {
             result = false;
             return false;
        }
    });

    if (fire && !result){
        throw new Error('Object does not define all properties');
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that, especially as an enumerated property on the prototype, and also when the "algorithm" is faulty (see comments on @AmitJoki's answer)?

Comment: @torazaburo Yeah, you're right. At first look @ AmitJoki's answer seemed like it would work. I've updated the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a general case of checking for presence of keys on a object, which can be done easily enough with

```
requiredParams.every(function(prop) { return prop in paramObj; })
```

It almost reads like natural language. "Taking the required parameters, is EVERY one of them IN the parameter object?".

Just wrap this in `function checkParams(paramObj, requiredParams)` for easy re-use.

More generally, this is the problem of asking if one list (in this case the list of required parameters) is included in  another list (the keys on the params object). So we can write a general routine for list inclusion:

```
function listIncluded(list1, list2) {
    return list1.every(function(e) { return list2.indexOf(e) !== -1; });
}
```

Then our parameter-checking becomes

```
function checkParams(paramObj, requiredParams) {
    return listIncluded(requiredParams, Object.keys(paramObj));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if object has at least some properties you can use this function without third parameter:

```
function hasRequiredProperties(propsNeeded, obj, strict) {

  if (strict) return Object.keys(obj).sort().join() == propsNeeded.sort().join();

  for (var i in propsNeeded ) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(propsNeeded[i])) return false;
  }
  return true;
};
```

Example:

```
 options = {url: {
        protocol: 'https:',
        hostname: 'encrypted.google.com',
        port: '80'
      }
    };

    propsNeeded = ['protocol', 'hostname'];

    hasRequiredProperties(propsNeeded, options.url); // true

    hasRequiredProperties(propsNeeded, options.url, true); // false
```